# Using PHP's XMLReader, how do I get the line number of the current node?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xmlreader, line-numbers

Using the XMLReader XML parser in PHP 5.3, I need to get the line number of the current node. A column number or total offset from the beginning of the file would be nice, too.

Hopefully I don't have to use some hack like parsing every raw node string for newlines (with `readOuterXML()`), but I don't see a `getLineNo()` property like in the DOM...

Answer (score 1):

See `XMLReader::expand` which returns a `DOMNode` element, which in turn supports `getLineNo()`

Comment: This works for some node types (XMLREADER::ELEMENT), but gives incorrect values for others (XMLREADER::END_ELEMENT) and not at all for others (XMLREADER::PI, XMLREADER::DOC_TYPE). I really need something that works for all node types..