# Which HTML Parser (preferably PHP) supports getting the offset of the current node in the input string?

Tags: php, html-parsing

I'm looking for an HTML or XML parser that lets one access the ***offset/position of the current element*** in the **input string or file**.

For example if walking through this string:

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
    <p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to get the starting position (including whitespace) of each `<p>` tag, here: `7` and `72`.

It'd be great if a PHP parser supported that natively (I've looked at [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php), and other libraries mentionned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/) but haven't found a way to do it), but otherwise any language/framework would be fine.

*Note: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2160533/593036), but less localized.*

Comment: not exactly the same but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530679/using-phps-xmlreader-how-do-i-get-the-line-number-of-the-current-node

Comment: @Gordon What concerns me is that [DOMNode::getLineNo](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.getlineno.php) seems to be pretty unreliable. If it's an underlying libxml2 bug as is asserted on that page, I'd probably need to find a non-libxml2-based solution. The other thing being that I would need the offset on the current line, not just the line number.

Comment: I am curious why you would need that anyway. The point of a parser is to parse the serialized XML into a data structure of some sort, which you then modify and serialize back to XML. The information where in the original XML string a node is located seems irrelevant then. At least I don't see the UseCase.

Comment: I'm building an EPUB reading system where "sentences" (sometimes spanning multiple XML nodes) are highlighted and their position is stored as start and end characters' offsets in the HTML file.

Comment: I wrote an html parser for pascal that tracks the offset. Guess it will not help you much, although it also reads most xml files...

Comment: What are you working on?

Comment: Is '7' the div (5) + new line (1?) + tab (1?) ?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I guess (number of characters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you could use [Generic XML parser class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4-PHP-Arbitrary-XML-parser-.html) (also on [github](https://github.com/manuellemos/xmlparser)).
According to the author's description:

- Parses arbitrary XML input and builds an array with the structure of all tag and data elements.
- It can validate and extract data from a whole XML document with just a single call. It supports validationg common tag value data types and can perform custom validations using a subclass.
- **Optionally, keeps track of the positions of each element to allow the determination of the exact location of elements that may be contextually in error.**
- Supports parsed file cache to minimize the overhead of parsing the same file repeatdly.
- Optimized parsing of simplified XML (SML) formats ignoring the tag attributes.
- Validate and extract data from a whole XML document with single function call

I've tested it with this code:

```
<?php

require('xml_parser.php');

$file_name = 'test.xml';
$error = XMLParseFile($parser, $file_name, 1, $file_name.'.cache');

foreach ($parser->structure as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val) && isset($val['Tag']) && !strcasecmp($val['Tag'], 'p')) {
        print_r($parser->positions[$key]);
    }
}

?>
```

The `test.xml` file contains your sample HTML snippet.
By running the script from the command line I get this output:

```
Array
(
    [Line] => 2
    [Column] => 7
    [Byte] => 12
)
Array
(
    [Line] => 3
    [Column] => 7
    [Byte] => 80
)
```

So, the `Byte` field is probably what you're looking for.
For a better understanding of how it works, have also a look at its [source code](https://github.com/manuellemos/xmlparser/blob/master/xml_parser.php#L72).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a bit concerned by the fact that the library seems a bit obscure – I'll keep on looking for now.

Comment: Do you know if the library's still maintained? Any other suggestions, maybe for languages/etc. ?

Comment: @julien_c The last documentation change is dated 2012-09-05, so I suppose that the library is still maintained. The library uses the [PHP Expat](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php) parser functions. For example, have a look at the [xml_get_current_byte_index](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-get-current-byte-index.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind coding in Java (after Java code there is a solution in PHP), you can use `indexOf` method in `String` class, getting the offset if this token.

Here is an example:

```
class Index {
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {   
        String token = "<p>";
        String input = "<p> hola </p> <p> adios </a>";
        int beginIdx = -1; 
        while ( (beginIdx = input.indexOf( token, beginIdx + 1 )) != -1 ) {                                                                                                                                         
            System.out.println( "Token at: " + beginIdx );
        }   
    }   
}
```

And the output is:

```
Token at: 0
Token at: 14
```

In PHP there is a similar function:

```
int strrpos ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

You can have a quick look to the "man" page about it (it has some examples): http://php.net/manual/es/function.strrpos.php

Comment: Not what the OP is looking for. This is not using an XML/HTML parser and will fail for any P elements not written exactly as `<p>`, e.g. having attributes or uppercase.

Comment: Then use a regular expression instead of a fixed string

Comment: I doubt he will find a parser that cares about the location of the input string, because the whole intent parsers is to remove those sort of concerns.

Comment: Use stripos instead of strrpos because stripos is case insensitive, and just search for "<p" instead of "<p>"

Comment: @RimuAtkinson I'm not just looking for <p> tags though (all kinds of tags)